# Why does my For loop continue after a user enters a specific amount?

Tags: java, for-loop

Any idea why won't the For loop kick out after the user-specified amount? The max amount a user can enter is 100.

```
class MakeTables
{
    private static final int MAX_NUMBER_TABLES = 100;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Table[] tables = new Table[MAX_NUMBER_TABLES];
        int i = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many tables would you like to create?"));

        for (i = 0; i < tables.length; i++)
        {
            tables[i] = new Table();
            tables[i].setHeight(Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter height:")));
            tables[i].setWeight(Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter weight:")));
            tables[i].setColor(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter color:"));
            tables[i].setNumberOfLegs(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of legs:")));

            if (tables[i] != null)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,(tables[i].toString()));

        } // end for
    } // end main

} // end class
```

Comment: You ask the user for the value `i` and then set it to 0. What's the point of doing that ?

Comment: _for loop kick out_ What does that even mean?

Comment: Presumably the user wants to only loop as many times as the user wanted tables. This would be solved if the array of tables was initialized to have the correct length in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
int j = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many tables would you like to create?"));
for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
{...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

You are asking the user for input and storing it in `i`

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many tables would 
                                                     + you like to create?"));
```

Then you reset the value of `i` to `0`.

```
for (i = 0; i < tables.length; i++)
```

---

**Solution**

```
int input = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many tables would 
                                                         + you like to create?"));

for (i = 0; i < input; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you initiate your for-loop, you reset the value the user has entered (which was stored in `i`) to 0, and the for-loop will thus execute from 0 till it does not meet the set condition (`i < tables.length`) anymore, so it goes from 0 to 100 regardless. I suggest you use a different iterator in your for loop, so you don't overwrite your user input. Furthermore, you should revisit your for-loop condition (think about it what you actually want!).